# How to tune Hadoop cluster to perform more than one task simultaneously?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I have more than 3 Hadoop batches (including SQOOP,HIVE,PIG jobs) and these batches are scheduled sequentially. While executing these batches jobs are getting stucked in ACCEPTED state if there are any previous job is running.

How to increase number of slots/container that will help in running jobs simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. Install more node managers
2. Limit the sizes of your maximum YARN container sizes
3. Use [different schedulers (and use queues)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html)